# Minecraft Server won't connect to a MariaDB or MySQL database

Tags: networking, server, mysql, minecraft, mariadb

I just switched to ubuntu and I'm trying to link my MariaDB database to my Minecraft server. When my Minecraft server tries to connect, it says this "Exception during pool initialization: HikariPool-20 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms." I've tried using localhost, 127.0.0.1, and 127.18.0.1 to connect to MariaDB, but none of them work.

I've even tried installing MySQL on an external machine and connecting to it that way, but I got the same error.

Thanks,
Redblock6

Comment: Could you give the full message that you have? This could give a hint to the reason why the connection is not available.  I suspect two possible causes: the Mariadb connector is not installed (see [this page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/) for further info) or there is an authentication problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the only message that I have. But I'll look into the MariaDB connector.